# query to join three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables -

```
books (bookid,bookname)

member(mid,mname)

transaction(transid,bookid,mid,ttype,issue_dt,due_dt,transremark)
```

Now i have a msql query-

```
SELECT (select count(*) FROM transaction where ttype='issue') as rownum,
transid,bookid,mid,ttype,issue_dt,due_dt,transremark 
FROM transaction 
WHERE ttype='issue' 
ORDER BY transid 
LIMIT 1 offset 3;
```

I want to get `bookname` and `mname` whose `bookid` and `mid` is present in above query..
Please suggest a query in which i could get the result of the above query along with bookname and mname..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
SELECT
count(1) as rownum,
transid,
b.bookid,
m.mid,
ttype,
   issue_dt,
    due_dt,
    transremark, 
    b.bookname,
    m.mname
    from transaction t
    INNER JOIN books b on (b.bookid=t.bookid)
    INNER JOIN member m on (t.mid=m.mid)
    where ttype='issue' ORDER BY transid LIMIT 1 offset 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .. I tried the query but it DID NOT work for me.. will you please suggest any other query..

Comment: Does DID NOT WORK refer to a syntactical error(If yes paste the error log) or is it not fetching the result you need(paste your expected result)..

Comment: I got the error - Column 'bookid' in field list is ambiguous ..

Comment: If you have thought on the error message for the sake of solving, you could have done that...
Have updated my query, please check now..
Actually as you can see there are two tables having the same column name, so you are getting this error, I have referred the table from which it needs to be selected

Comment: Now its showing 'Empty set, 20 warnings' error .. Please help..

Comment: are you getting any result

Comment: No result ..Just the error - 'Empty set,120 warnings (0.02 sec)' ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
SELECT bookname, mname, temp.*
FROM books, member,
(SELECT (select count(*) FROM transaction where ttype='issue') as 
rownum,transid,bookid,mid,ttype,issue_dt,due_dt,transremark 
from transaction where 
ttype='issue' 
ORDER BY transid LIMIT 3,1) as temp
WHERE books.bookid = temp.bookid
AND member.mid = temp.mid
```

If it does not work, you can try removing **LIMIT** clause

Comment: Thanks for the response .. I tried both the queries but it DID NOT work for me.. will you please suggest any other query..

Comment: Can you add it to sqlfiddle and send us the link to try out.

Answer (score 0):

In the following given some query that may be helpful for you. I submitted those without testing. If you face any syntax error then please rewrite this. And also if you think you wanted any other thinks then you can inform....

```
SELECT transaction.*, member.mname, books.bookname
FROM transaction
INNER JOIN member ON transaction.mid = member.mid
INNER JOIN books ON transaction.bookid = books.bookid
WHERE transaction.ttype='issue' ;
```

By using this query you will got individually row for every member.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.bookname, m.mname 
FROM (transaction AS t 
LEFT JOIN books AS b
ON b.bookid = t.bookid)
LEFT JOIN member AS m 
ON m.mid = t.mid
WHERE t.ttype='issue';
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE books(
  bookid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bookname VARCHAR (50)
);


CREATE TABLE member(
  mid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  mname VARCHAR (30)
);

CREATE TABLE transaction(
  transid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bookid INT,
  mid INT,
  ttype VARCHAR (10),
  issue_dt DATETIME,
  due_dt DATETIME,
  transremark varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO books(bookname)
VALUES ("Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"), ("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"), ("Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban");

INSERT INTO member(mname)
VALUES  ('bob'), ('jack'), ('joe');

INSERT INTO transaction(bookid,mid,ttype,issue_dt,due_dt,transremark)
VALUES (1,1,'issue', curdate(),curdate()+ INTERVAL 5 DAY, "UPS"),
(1,2,'issue', curdate(),curdate()+ INTERVAL 5 DAY, "UPS"),
(3,1,'issue', curdate(),curdate()+ INTERVAL 5 DAY, "UPS"),
(2,1,'issue', curdate(),curdate()+ INTERVAL 20 DAY, "UPS"),
(3,3,'no_issue', curdate(),curdate()+ INTERVAL 20 DAY, "FEDEX");
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b0d/5

**EDIT: With LIMIT**

```
SELECT b.bookname, m.mname 
FROM (transaction AS t 
LEFT JOIN books AS b
ON b.bookid = t.bookid)
LEFT JOIN member AS m 
ON m.mid = t.mid
WHERE t.ttype='issue'
LIMIT 1 offset 3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b0d/7

Perhaps I misunderstand but you request for the bookname and member name only. If you want more info you can use this query as well. Substitute SELECT * FROM in the current query above.

The best of luck with you project.